# SQL Server Management Studio commands latency

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, networking, ssms

I noticed, while trying to run an UPDATE script on a remote DB server geographically dislocated in another country, that the command executes successfully in about 1 hour if I run it from Management Studio on my local machine. If, instead, i run it directly on Management Studio that is installed on the server, it takes about 10 minutes to execute.

So, my question is: is latency important even if there is no "data traffic" generated by my command? I would expect latency when i execute an INSERT or SELECT command because there is effectively data that has to be sent from one machine to the other. That's not my case because the UPDATE commands i'm executing don't produce any output and don't have input data inside them.

Comment: Post your update script.

Comment: You have two servers Server A and Server B both on different regions. You run a CRUD statement on Server A that will insert data on Server B. What happens is that a transaction will be sent to Server B, it wont effect Server B(If its a small transaction) but rather your resources on Server A will have a huge impact even if its a small transaction.

Comment: There's something here that you're not telling us. Unless your connection is so slow that it takes 50 minutes to send the SQL statement to the server, there must be something else going on that slows it down.

Comment: Are rowcount messages returned? If so, add `SET NOCOUNT ON` to eliminate latency returned by those.